# Unable to display an image from API in ASP Net Core Web API project

Tags: api, rest, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I had made a API project using ASP Dot Net Core Web API  and it passes some datas including Image name also like

```
{
    "packId": 12,
    "packageName": "qwerty",
    "duration": 3,
    "location": "test",
    "facilities": "test",
    "coverImage": "9a76f953-5287-4e99-ab03-2c6a1cc2c8ca.jpg",
    "country": "adasda",
    "image1": "9b937694-c342-42a8-8114-a1677478fdd1.jpg",
    
  },
```

but I can't display the Image using the image name and also by url passing like.
text
coverImage folder is in the main section folder
[image: folder structure]

What can I do to display the image?

I need to display the image while I fetch the API in any frontend technologies